# Array of Arrays | 2D Array input output variables (not hard coded values)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having an issue with the use of the 2D array.  If I replace the array with system.out.println, I obtain all 5 of my items successfully so I think the issue is the array syntax on the input and output.  Almost all of the posts I've read on this topic reference hard coded values so I'm hoping this post (once the issue is identified) will help others in the future using non hard coded values.  Thanks!

```
    int count = 10;
    String[][] array2d = new String[count][2];
    int row = 0, column = 0;

            while(count > 0){   
            if(count <= 5){
             array2d[row][column] = variable1 + variable2;
                    row++;
                    column++;
                }                   
                count--;                    
            }

        for(row = 0; row < 5; row++){
        System.out.println("Item #: " + array2d[row][0] + " Item Description: " + array2d[0][column]);
        }           
    }
```

The above was resolved by changing the following:

```
 int count = 10;
 String[][] array2d = new String[count][2];
 int row = 0, column1 = 0, column2 = 2;

            while(count > 0){   
            if(count <= 5){
             array2d[row][column1] = variable1;
                     array2d[row][column2] = variable2;
                    row++;
                }                   
                count--;                    
            }
        for(row = 0; row < 5; row++){
        System.out.println("Item #: " + array2d[row][column1] + " Item Description: " + array2d[row][column2]);
        }           
    }
```

Comment: I see a potential out of bounds error.  You call array2d[row][column] and call column++.  It looks like count goes from 10 to 5 in this while loop, so column goes from 0 to 5, on a size 2 array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2D arrays are here to represent data that is indexable with 2 indices.

If you need a 1D array of elements and use the 2nd dimension to index the elements' properties, then you are misusing OOP.

You should instead declare classes like this:

```
class Item {
    String id;
    String description;
}
```

And use a 1D array of `Item`s:

```
int count = 10;
Item[] array = new Item[count];
int row = 0;
while(count > 0){   
    if (count <= 5) {
        array[row].id = variable1;
        array[row].description = variable2;
        row++;
    }                   
    count--;                    
}
for(row = 0; row < 5; row++){
    System.out.println("Item #: " + array[row].id + " Item Description: " + array[row].description);
}
```

Comment: Much better, thank you for taking the time to understand what I'm trying to accomplish and educating me on the right approach.

Comment: @PadawanDeveloper This is the purpose of this forum ;) I'm glad to help

Answer (score 0):

In your above code the array dimensions are: [count][2]. but your code is incrementing column and row variables equally.

```
            array2d[row][column] = line + String.valueOf(count);
            row++;
            column++;
```

You need to check value of column and reset it when it crosses 2.

```
        if(count <= 5 ){
          if(column >= 2) 
              column=0;
          array2d[row][column] = line + String.valueOf(count);
          row++;
          column++;
        }
```

Comment: @ user2881767 Thanks, your comment got me thinking on how I was traversing the columns.

Comment: The code you have edited can still cause errors as your column size is 2 and you are placing values for indices 0 and 2(column1=0, column2=2). You are missing index 1, and index 2 makes column size 3.